# How to add widget in react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I wouldike to add this this widget (source : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@layerzerolabs/aptos-bridge-widget) :

```
<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/@layerzerolabs/aptos-bridge-widget@latest/element.js"
  defer
  integrity="sha384-${checksum}"
  async
></script>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/@layerzerolabs/aptos-bridge-widget@latest/element.css"
/>
<aptos-bridge />
```

in my component react : `src/pages/home/index.tsx` :

```
return (
    <>
<Root>
        <IconContainer>
          <img width="500" height="500px" src={logo} />
        </IconContainer>
        <aptos-bridge />
      </Root>
    </>
```

But they show me always the same error : `Property 'aptos-bridge' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.  TS2339`

I already tried to put the `<script> & <link>` in the index.html but when I put the aptos-bridge balise on my react component same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert all the widget's requirements into the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property of a JSX-element.

Try the following:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}} />
```

Where `data` is a string containing:

```
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/@layerzerolabs/aptos-bridge-widget@latest/element.js" defer integrity="sha384-${checksum}" async></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@layerzerolabs/aptos-bridge-widget@latest/element.css" />
<aptos-bridge />`
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback ! you mean I insert the div balise in my react component ?

Comment: You're welcome. Try that, yes.

Comment: It's a pleasure to have helped you. Good luck!